# How to read a pandas date column as date type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this code. I can download a spreadsheet and load a worksheet as a data frame. But the Date column is not getting converted as expected.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_BH_spreadsheet(URLS, SPREADSHEET_NAME):
    resp = requests.get(URLS)
    output = open(SPREADSHEET_NAME, 'wb')
    output.write(resp.content)
    output.close()
    df_NA_RIG_COUNT = pd.read_excel(open(SPREADSHEET_NAME, 'rb'), sheet_name='US Oil & Gas Split', index_col=None,header = 'infer', skiprows=6)
    df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'] )
    
    return df_NA_RIG_COUNT
```

By passing the URL and filename, we get the data frame.

```
get_BH_spreadsheet('https://rigcount.bakerhughes.comstatic-files/027e0bcc-86ec-407b-9029-b5bd3bf1982b', 'North America Rotary Rig Count - Jan 2000 - Current.xlsx')
```

This, however does not give the desired result. What can I do differently to get proper date time type?

```
df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `converters` as parameter of `read_excel` to convert excel dates (elapsed days since 1899-12-30):

```
df_NA_RIG_COUNT = pd.read_excel(
    'north_america_rotary_rig_count_jan_2000_-_current.xlsb',
    sheet_name='US Oil & Gas Split', skiprows=6, 
    converters={'Date': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')}
)

# OR
df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'], 
                                         unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')
```

Output:

```
>>> df_NA_RIG_COUNT
           Date  Oil  Gas  Misc  Total     % Oil     % Gas
0    1987-07-17  559  337    26    922  0.606291  0.365510
1    1987-07-24  565  331    21    917  0.616140  0.360960
2    1987-07-31  605  346    22    973  0.621788  0.355601
3    1987-08-07  613  349    21    983  0.623601  0.355036
4    1987-08-14  620  352    26    998  0.621242  0.352705
...         ...  ...  ...   ...    ...       ...       ...
1888 2023-09-22  507  118     5    630  0.804762  0.187302
1889 2023-09-29  502  116     5    623  0.805778  0.186196
1890 2023-10-06  497  118     4    619  0.802908  0.190630
1891 2023-10-13  501  117     4    622  0.805466  0.188103
1892 2023-10-20  502  118     4    624  0.804487  0.189103

[1893 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: I am getting the correct answer. But don't understand origin = '1899-12-30'. Where can I read about this? The pandas documentation mentions origin as January 1, 4713 BC for Julian. Is the year 1899 mentioned just to include all the years of 20th century?

Comment: The origin for [Excel Date](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487) is 1900-1-1. There is an obscure reason to use 1899-12-30. I think it's because Excel treats the year 1900 as a leap year.

Comment: (So my code is inaccurate for dates between 1900-1-1 and 1900-2-28!)

Answer (score 0):

If the pd.to_datetime function is not parsing the date column as expected, it's possible that the date format in your Excel file is not recognized correctly. You can specify the date format explicitly using the format parameter of the pd.to_datetime function to ensure it's parsed correctly.

***Example:***

```
df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_NA_RIG_COUNT['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```